# Querying application state in a loop prevents exit

Tags: applescript

I'm looking to query the playerState property of iTunes while it's open. Here's the starting version:

```
var itunes = Application('iTunes')

while (true) {
    if (itunes.running()) {
        console.log(itunes.playerState())
    }
    delay(0.01)
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it prevents iTunes from properly closing (as in right click -> Quit). I believe this is happening because getting the `playerState` property produces a call to launch iTunes. (Without the `itunes.running()` guard, iTunes will launch as soon as the script starts.)

Increasing the `delay` is a workaround that decreases the probability of iTunes staying open after a quit, but doesn't make it zero or truly solve the issue.

I see two solution pathways:

1. Is there a way to access application properties without the side effect of launching the application? (Fairly certain the answer to this is currently no.)
2. Can an AppleScript query whether an application received the SIGTERM/SIGKILL signal? Or know that an application is in the "quitting" phase?